# UWP How to know if an enum value is added in a later version

Tags: c#, enums, uwp, windows-10-universal

For my UWP app, in order to support minimum version of 10240, I have to write adaptive code, i.e. detect the presence of particular API at runtime. But in order to do so, I need to know if an API was present or not in 10240 or was added in a later version. It's OK for classes since it's written (normally at the end of each page) in Microsoft's documentation, but how do I get that info for added methods or enum values?

For example, from this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code#adaptive-code-examples, it's written that ChatWithoutEmoji is added in 14393 (1607). But in documentation page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.InputScopeNameValue, it's only written that enum is present in 10240, but nowhere I can know one of its values, ChatWithoutEmoji, is present only from 14393.

[Update]
Note that I know already how to detect API at runtime, my question is how to known when I need do runtime check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect which APIs are present in UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342434/detect-which-apis-are-present-in-uwp-app)

Comment: You don't need to know in which version an enum was added. You need to know, whether it is available on the platform your application currently runs on. What's wrong with the solution you linked to, i.e. calling `ApiInformation.IsEnumNamedValuePresent`?

Comment: If I start writing new code without reading the first article before, I will not know that ChatWithoutEmoji is added after, thus I will not check with ApiInformation.IsEnumNamedValuePresent. Either I need search around the net for every enum value I'm going to use or call ApiInformation.IsEnumNamedValuePresent every access is nowhere near acceptable.

Comment: It's like with win32 APIs -- if you want to use a feature, read the doc page to see when that feature was added.  Function call or specific enumeration, the idea is the same.

Comment: @DaveS That is the whole point, the doc page does not mention that info.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Bugs in documentation make life more exciting.  Choose NO to "Is this page helpful?" at the bottom of the page and point out the problem.

Comment: @DaveS I just did. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I normally just use the latest rtm SDK and then before sending it to QA, reduce the SDK version to lowest supported and see if any compile-time errors come up.

Comment: @JustinXL In my case, the compilation will always fail by other code that also use new feature before it reach my code. Thus I will have to comments all theses codes (there are a lot) before I can know if my code pass or not.